# android:layout_span is not being showed in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tablelayout

layout_span does not work and when I wrote android:layout_s and press ctrl+space for getting possible suggestions, eclipse does not show any option for layout_span

ignoring this I coppied and pasted it (`layout_span="2"`). but not gives the expected result. it divides row as something like below

```
------------------------------------
|  (about)%40  |     (about)%60    |
------------------------------------
|   %33    |     %33   |     %33   |
------------------------------------
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="200dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Column 1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/BoldBlue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="Column 2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Normal" />


</TableRow>
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/BoldBlue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Column 2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Normal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Column 3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Normal" />


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="BoldBlue">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BoldGreenCenter">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Normal">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I have trouble. couldn't fixed it please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make that with layout_weight attr. try below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3366FF"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: It's so strange. I set first textview weight=2, second textview weight=5 then get desired result. But this will behave in different screen sizes

Comment: Have your tried layout I've posted? I've added an screen shot of the result. Isn't it what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks :) yes your code worked. thanks but what is wrong with layout_span. why it is not working

Comment: I've always used layout_weight attr on table rows (cause I know that TableRow is a subclass of LinearLayout). And I think if you apply correct values for layout_span attr to all views under TableLayout (I mean to all TextViews in your layout) that will work too. For instance try to set to all TextViews' layout_span value. At first row 1,2 and second row 1,1,1.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `layout_span="1"` to the firs column which at row 1

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse , XML code assist will not prompts the attribute “android:layout_span“, “android:layout_column” and many other useful TableLayout attributes, no idea why, may be bug. Just put the attribute inside, it’s still compile and run.
[more](http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98)